# Display error from a deployed plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Finally, after hours of working, I finally got my plug-in to work in the Virtual Eclipse application (the one where you can test your plug-in). Happy, I created a feature and a site to deploy the plug-in. After installing, it seems my plug-in isn't working.

Now, I don't know where the errors are or why isn't it working because I was only using `System.out.println(error)` when I was testing it.

What do I need to use when I want to display the error when a plug-in has been installed in the actual Eclipse application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write messages to the Eclipse log. This is the `.log` file in the workspace `.metadata` directory (both hidden on some platforms).

You can write to the log using the `ILog` interface.

If you have an Activator class which extends `AbstractUIPlugin` or `Plugin` to can get the `ILog` by calling the `getLog()` method of `Plugin`.

Alternatively you can get the log with:

```
Bundle bundle = ... your plug-in bundle

ILog log = Platform.getLog(bundle);
```

Write an entry to the log with something like:

```
IStatus status = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, "message", exception);

log.log(status);
```

where `exception` is any exception you want to report or `null`.

You can get the plug-in bundle with:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

or

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

Comment: Hi @greg-449. Where can I see the bundle of the plug-in? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @greg-449 Thank you! Is the .log file, the one with no filename?

Comment: It is just called `.log`